# Python, killed?

Tags: python, math

OK, so I've finally started with math in python, which is (so far) surprisingly not as hard as I thought it would be(I don't know any calculus, or trigonometry, and only know basic algebra).
I'm trying to create a program from scratch that factors quadratic equations. Here is what I have so far (Sorry if it's poorly written):

```
def factor(arg):    
    o = arg
    n = o
    x = 2
    factors = [o]

    while abs(o) >= x:
        if (o) % x == 0:
            n = o / x
            factors.append(n)
            x += 1
        else:
            x += 1

    return factors

A = int(raw_input("What is A in your quadratic equation?   A = "))
B = int(raw_input("What is B in your quadratic equation?   B = "))
C = int(raw_input("What is C in your quadratic equation?   C = "))

Br = abs(B) + abs(A)            # Range of B
Bpf = range (-Br, Br + 1)       # Possible factors of B
ACpf = factor(A * C)            # Possible factors of (A * C)

for i in ABpf:
    ACpf.append(-i) 

cf = []                          # Common factors

for i in Bpf:
    for j in ACpf:
        if i == j:
            cf.append(i)

print cf
```

I ran this script through the terminal, it asked me what A B and C are, then it  froze up for about thirty seconds. After it unfroze below what I typed it said 'killed'.
Does anyone know what caused this? I appreciate any answers or advice.

Comment: Are you running this on your own computer or one at work/school? It sounds rather like you ran over your CPU quota on a shared machine.

Comment: The _first_ thing you should learn about trigonometry is how to spel it :-)

Comment: Factoring a quadratic equation quickly and easily is a solved problem. Python even supports complex roots.

Comment: @GuySirton - This isn't a recursive function so I doubt it's a stack overflow.

Comment: @OP - Looks like you have a typo... "for i in ABpf:"

Comment: IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I think this is a homework problem (kindall is probably correct in his shared-computer guess), so that may not be an option. And, paxdiablo: it's "spell" :p.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't say it was a stack overflow, I said you might be using too much CPU.

Comment: @kindall - Sorry, read it too quickly. That comment was meant for Guy Sirton.

Comment: To be clear, Python does not have any such behavior built-in so far as I know, so something external to Python must be killing your script.

Comment: @hex4def6, that was part of the humour. Even if it _wasn't,_ I'd still claim it was :-)

Comment: This doesn't behave the way you described for me.
But rather fails with "name 'ABpf' is not defined" as indeed, ABpf is not defined when you use it.

Comment: The values where A = 1, B = -5, C = -14. And @OP, In the actual script for some reason I typed ABpf instead of ACpf, so on here to prevent confusion I just switched it up, I must have forgot one.

Comment: @Kindall, I'm running on my own computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code a bit like this:

```
def factor(arg):    
    o = arg
    n = o
    x = 2
    factors = [o]

    while abs(o) >= x:
    if (o) % x == 0:
        n = o / x
        factors.append(n)
        x += 1
    else:
        x += 1

    return factors

A = int(raw_input("What is A in your quadratic equation?   A = "))
B = int(raw_input("What is B in your quadratic equation?   B = "))
C = int(raw_input("What is C in your quadratic equation?   C = "))

Br = abs(B) + abs(A)            # Range of B
Bpf = range (-Br, Br + 1)       # Possible factors of B
ABpf = factor(A * C)            # Possible factors of (A * C)
ACpf = []
for i in ABpf:
    ACpf.append(i)
    ACpf.append(-1*i) 

cf = []                          # Common factors

for i in Bpf:
    for j in ACpf:
    if i == j:
        cf.append(i)

print cf
```

Now try running it. You should get a result.

Comment: `if (o) % x == 0:` is better written as `if not o % x:`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is in these lines:

```
ACpf = factor(A * C)            # Possible factors of (A * C)

for i in ABpf:
    ACpf.append(-i)
```

Try this instead:

```
ACpf = factor(A * C)            # Possible factors of (A * C)

for i in ACpf[:]:               # Loop over a copy of ACpf
    ACpf.append(-i)
```

The [:] notation is used to copy the list.  That makes sure that you aren't mutating the list (growing it) while looping over it.

Also here is a little clean-up of the code for factor():

```
def factor(arg):
    o = arg
    factors = [o]

    for x in range(2, o+1):
        if o % x == 0:
            n = o // x
            factors.append(n)

    return factors
```